# Gridview Label Appear in a Selected Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, aspxgridview

I has a Gridview called Gridview1 which is binded to a datasource.
and I have a ItemTemplate at Column 5 within it contain a 
- Linkbutton called search
- Label called lbl_password , visible press to true
- Label called txt_password , visible set to false

code in done in asp.net webForm , .aspx

when link button pressed this function will get the ID at cell 1  in the row tat button clicked

```
GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
string fieldID = grdrow.Cells[1].Text;
```

Now i want to know how can I make the txt and lbl become visible when the button pressed

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean when link button pressed you want to make the text and label from the same row to be visible.For that purpose you can just use the `findcontrol` method on gridview row to find the control you need.

If that's what you want then in link button click event you can do as follow,

```
   protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        ((TextBox)grdrow.FindControl("yourtextboxID")).Visible = true;
        ((Label)grdrow.FindControl("yourLabelID")).Visible = true;
    }
```

[Here is more info on findcontrol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.findcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).